# Change style of auto-import from `~/directory/file` to `@/directory/file`?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, nuxt.js

This is kind of a silly question, but it bothers me. I have a Nuxt3 application that I'm building with Vscode. Any time I have something auto-import, Vscode will automatically import using the `~/directory/file` prefix, and I'd prefer for it to import with the `@/directory/file` prefix. Is there a simple Vscode or tsconfig option I can alter to change this?

My existing tsconfig only extends the one that comes with Nuxt:

```json
{
  // https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/typescript
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question, many people have been bothered by it too. Because in the default `tsconfig.json` generated by Nuxt 3, `~` is before `@` in `compilerOptions.paths`. You can alter the order by the following config:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  typescript: {
    tsConfig: {
      compilerOptions: {
        paths: {
          '@': ['.'],
          '@/*': ['./*'],
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Don't forget to run `nuxi prepare` to regenerate `.nuxt/tsconfig.json` after modifying the config.